# How to get properties hasid/key with vertexes info in one gremlin query or Gremlin.Net

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, janusgraph

I try to get properties which has key or id in following query by Gremlin.Net, but vertex info(id and label) in VertexProperty is null in result.

`g.V().Properties<VertexProperty>().HasKey(somekey).Promise(p => p.ToList())`

So i try another way, but it's return class is Path, and i had to write an ugly code for type conversion.

`g.V().Properties<VertexProperty>().HasKey(somekey).Path().By(__.ValueMap<object, object>(true))`

Is there a better way to achieve this requirement

Comment: In seconde way, i got a result for nearly 8 minutes in a graph has 100,000 vertexes :(

Comment: Can you please clarify what you're expecting to get back exactly? You want to find all vertices that have a specific property key, like `name`, and then get all of their properties, their vertex id and label?

Comment: @FlorianHockmann Sorry for confusion, I have two cases, one is I want to find all properties has some key, and get properties info(id, key, value) with their vertex id and label, i tried g.V().elementMap(propertyKey)，but i can't get property id; The other is get property by id, i tried g.V().properties().hasId(propertyId), but i can't get its vertex id and label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think basically the only thing missing to get what you want is [the `Project()` step](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.5.0/reference/#project-step).

In order to find all vertices that have a certain property key and then get their id, label, and then all information about that property, you can use this traversal:

```cs
g.V().
    Has(someKey).
    Project<object>("vertexId", "vertexLabel", "property").
        By(T.Id).
        By(T.Label).
        By(__.Properties<object>(someKey).ElementMap<object>()).
    Promise(t => t.ToList());
```

This returns a `Dictionary` where the keys are the arguments given to the `Project` step.

If you instead want to filter by a certain property id instead of a property key, then you can do it in a very similar way:

```cs
g.V().
    Where(__.Properties<object>().HasId(propertyId)).
    Project<object>("vertexId", "vertexLabel", "property").
        By(T.Id).
        By(T.Label).
        By(__.Properties<object>(someKey).ElementMap<object>()).
    Promise(t => t.ToList());
```

This filters in both cases first the vertices to only have vertices that have the properties we are looking for. That way, we can use the `Project()` step afterwards to get the desired data back.
`ElementMap` should give all information back about the properties that you want.

Note however that these traversals will most likely require a full graph scan in JanusGraph, meaning that it has to iterate over all vertices in your graph. The reason is that these traversals cannot use an index which would make them much more efficient. So, for larger graphs, the traversals will probably not be feasible.

If you had the vertex ids available instead of the property ids in the second traversal, then you could make the traversal a lot more efficient by replacing `g.V().Where([...])` simply with `g.V(id)`.